# How do I fix an issue with RewriteMap

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

for some reason my RewriteMap is not working.

Setup is:

- Apache Pre VirtualHost Include

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap redirectsmap dbm:/home/sitename/hredirects.db
```

- .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond     ${redirectsmap:$1}     >""     [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*) ${redirectsmap:$1}     [R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

- map file contains (similar to this but thousands of entries):

```
/main /article-main/name 
/article/search /search
```

I have tested a normal 3xx redirect in the Apache Pre VirtualHost Include and .htaccess file, and it works fine, but for some reason the RewriteMap does nothing... any ideas please?

(Server is a linux VPS running WHM/Cpanel on CentOs7 / Website is Wordpress on PHP 8 / DNS behind CloudFlare)

Comment: Can you try this condition: `RewriteCond ${redirectsmap:$1} .`

Comment: "I have tested a normal 301 redirect in the Apache Pre VirtualHost Include" - What about testing a normal 3xx redirect in the `.htaccess` file (but you should always _test_ with a 302 first), which appears to be where the problem is. What values/URLs does your rewrite map contain? Bear in mind that the URL-path matched in `.htaccess` is not the same as in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context. For instance, the rule you've posted is dependent on `RewriteBase` (or your rewrite map is wrong) - you should remove this dependency.

Comment: @anubhava that made no difference; thanks though.

Comment: @MrWhite sure; 3xx redirects work fine in the .htaccess file. The rewrite map file/s contains similar to:
/main /article-main/name &
/article/search /search

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond     ${redirectsmap:$1}     >""     [NC]
> RewriteRule     ^(.*) ${redirectsmap:$1}     [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> ---
>
> map file contains (similar to this but thousands of entries):
>
> ```
> /main /article-main/name 
> /article/search /search
> ```

That's the problem, you are not passing the same URL-path to your rewrite map that is stored in the map file. In a `.htaccess` context, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not start with a slash, so you are effectively passing `main` (not `/main`), which fails to match the URL-path in your map file. (This would, however, have worked in a *server* or *virtualhost* context.)

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond ${redirectsmap:/$1} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*) %1 [R=301,L]
```

No need to call the rewrite map twice, since you can capture the return value in the *condition* and use the backreference `%1` in the *substitution* string instead.

And no need for the `NC` flag on the *condition* or the `^` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Unless you are also redirecting the root directory (homepage) then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `(.*)` to `(.+)` - to avoid unnecessarily matching the homepage.

(Test first with a 302 - temporary - redirect, to avoid potential caching issues.)

Alternatively, use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead:

```
RewriteCond ${redirectsmap:%{REQUEST_URI}} (.+)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

(Again, if not redirecting the homepage then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^` to `.`.)